# how can I test the type of annotation in popplerqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, poppler

popplerqt5 is a pdf rendering library for python.

Annotation is an abstract class from this library. It has many subclasses, such as LinkAnnotation. How can I know the Subclass from an Annotation object?

```
import popplerqt5 as poppler
import PyQt5
import PyQt5.QtXml

def main():

    file = 'file.pdf'

    doc = poppler.Poppler.Document.load(file)

    annotations     = doc.page(1).annotations()

    for annotation in annotations:
        print (annotation)
        # if isinstance(annotation, poppler.LinkAnnotation):
            # print ("Link")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This doesn't work, LinkAnnotation is not defined. I am using Python 3.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If your error is that `LinkAnnotation` is not defined, then the question is, why do you expect it to be? What is that class, and where does it come from? Have you imported it correctly? Maybe you just need to prefix its name with its module or package (i.e. `if isinstance(annotation, somemodule.LinkAnnotation):`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `poppler.Poppler.LinkAnnotation`:

```
import popplerqt5 as poppler

def main():
    file = 'test.pdf'
    doc = poppler.Poppler.Document.load(file)
    annotations     = doc.page(2).annotations()
    for annotation in annotations:
        if isinstance(annotation, poppler.Poppler.LinkAnnotation):
            print ("Link")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```